# Using a type without namespace specification or import

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I know that this is not really clean but it is possible as I am seeing it right now.
I have no import for System.Web.UI.WebControls. All I have is a reference to System.Web.
The type is used like this:

```
    Private plhZoneContexte As PlaceHolder
```

PlaceHolder is under System.Web.UI.WebControls so I should prefix it like this if not imported:

```
    Private plhZoneContexte As System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder
```

The problem is that I can't use imports or prefixes for this case. I'm not allowed to do this kind of modification. This is the way the app worked before, and this is the way the newer version should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: yes it works, you just have to do more typing. You still have to reference the assemblies though.

Comment: And more specifically? It is not something easy to look for in Google and if someone knows the way to do that or just has some suggestion on how to look for it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand, you just type the namespace in for each identifier, if you're lucky you have intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could import the namespace in the project properties. That would remove the necessity of adding Imports or prefixes.

[image: Project properties for a VB.NET project]

Comment: Ok, only have to check it on the list found on the reference menu. This is easy, but I just didn't know it was possible before now. Thanks for the help.